# Unable to load BIRT chart inside jsp

Tags: java, jsp, charts, birt

i got a problem when load BIRT chart report into jsp..if i use table for my report it will show nice but when i change to chart it just showing blank page in my jsp..how can i solve this problem ??

here is my html render.

```
public Resolution htmlReport() throws EngineException, SemanticException {
            ByteArrayOutputStream reportOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            String path = getCompassContext().getServletContext().getRealPath(
                    "/report");

            // @TODO
            String user = getCompassContext().getUser().getUsername();
            birtReport.setUser(user);
            birtReport.setBirtEngine(getCompassContext().getBirtEngine());

            path = CompassConfig.getBirtReport(); //+ "/login_time.rptdesign";
            birtReport.setReportDesignPath(path);
            birtReport.setReportDesignName("/test.rptdesign");
            /**
             * Generates the html report.
             * 
             * @return forward to the jsp page
             * @throws EngineException when opening report design or reunning the report
             * @throws SemanticException when changing properties of DesignElementHandle
             */
             // set output options
                IHTMLRenderOption options = new HTMLRenderOption();

                options.setOutputFormat(IHTMLRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_HTML);
                options.setOutputStream(reportOutput);
                options.setEmbeddable(false);
               // options.setBaseImageURL(context.getRequest().getContextPath() + "/images");
               //options.setImageDirectory(context.getServletContext().getRealPath("/images"));
                options.setImageHandler(new HTMLServerImageHandler());
                options.setMasterPageContent(true);

               birtReport.generateReport(options);

                return new StreamingResolution("text/html", new ByteArrayInputStream(reportOutput.toByteArray()));
            }
```

here is my BIRT engine

```
public void generateReport(IRenderOption options) throws EngineException,
            SemanticException {

        generateParamaters();

        // get the engine
        IReportEngine birtReportEngine = birtEngine;

        // open the report design
        String path = reportDesignPath + "/" + reportDesignName;
        IReportRunnable design = birtReportEngine.openReportDesign(path);

        // create task to run and render report
        IRunAndRenderTask task = birtReportEngine
                .createRunAndRenderTask(design);

        Map<String, Object> appContext = task.getAppContext();
        Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection();
        appContext.put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection", con);

        HashMap<String, String[]> multiValParam = getMultiValParam();
        if(multiValParam != null && multiValParam.size() > 0) {
            Set<String> key = multiValParam.keySet();
            Iterator<String> ite = key.iterator();

            while(ite.hasNext()) {
                String paramName = (String) ite.next();
                String[] paramValues = multiValParam.get(paramName);

                task.setParameterValue(paramName, paramValues);
            }
        }
        task.setParameterValues(getParameter());
        task.setRenderOption(options);
        task.setAppContext(appContext);

        // run report
        task.run();
        task.close();
    }
```

really need help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

i'll already find the answer..you need to put inside html render below setEmbeddable(true)

options.setBaseImageURL(getCompassContext().getRequest().getContextPath() + "/images");
options.setImageDirectory(getCompassContext().getServletContext().getRealPath("/images"));

and need to put this code inside the generate report below appContext.put

DesignElementHandle reportChart = design.getDesignHandle().getModuleHandle().findElement("reportChart");